# How to load csvs with different structures using CSVProvider?

Tags: csv, f#

Any Ideas? My current code is below.

```
let rawdata csvfile 
        FinCsv.Load(data).Rows
        |> Seq.filter (fun row -> row.Id <> "---")
        |> Seq.filter (fun row -> row.Country <> "Honduras")
        |> Seq.filter (fun row -> row.Tax <> 0)
        |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> row.Country)
        |> Seq.averageBy (fun row -> row.Tax)
        |> List.ofSeq
```

Comment: The CSV Provider uses column position to extract the data.  Unless your different CSV formats have the `Id`, `Country`, and `Tax` columns as the first 3 columns in the same order, you'll have to either pre-process the files to standardize the format, or use Statically Resolved Type Parameters as discussed here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765832/how-to-pass-a-type-as-a-function-parameter-in-f/50766560#50766560

Comment: in this case, how would I use them? The link is a different case.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach one could also follow the object-oriented approach of declaring an interface and types to represent each file structure that also implement the interface.  For a more functional approach, one could have function parameters that get the id, country, and tax respectively.  Without looking at the question much harder than that, though, I would lean toward the suggestion of statically-resolved type parameters.

Comment: Seriously, what's the point deleting text and code from your question? Now answers people spent their time on are without context!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with statically-resolved type parameters is that the syntax is cumbersome.  Here's an example:

```
let inline snippet< ^T when ^T : (member Id : string)
                        and ^T : (member Country : string)
                        and ^T : (member Tax : float) >
                        xs =
    xs
    |> Seq.filter (fun row -> ( ^T : (member Id : string) row) <> "---")
    |> Seq.filter (fun row -> ( ^T : (member Country : string) row) <> "South America")
    |> Seq.filter (fun row -> ( ^T : (member Tax : float) row) <> 0.0)
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> ( ^T : (member Country : string) row))
    |> Seq.map (fun (country, rows) -> country, (rows |> Seq.averageBy (fun row -> ( ^T : (member Tax : float) row))))
    |> List.ofSeq
```

(I've modified the averageBy call so it makes more sense than the one in the question.)

You can actually let the compiler infer the constraints rather than declaring them explicitly:

```
let inline snippet xs =
    xs
    |> Seq.filter (fun row -> ( ^T : (member Id : string) row) <> "---")
    |> Seq.filter (fun row -> ( ^T : (member Country : string) row) <> "South America")
    |> Seq.filter (fun row -> ( ^T : (member Tax : float) row) <> 0.0)
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> ( ^T : (member Country : string) row))
    |> Seq.map (fun (country, rows) -> country, (rows |> Seq.averageBy (fun row -> ( ^T : (member Tax : float) row))))
    |> List.ofSeq
```

As an alternative, you could require the caller to pass value-getter functions:

```
let snippet2 getId getCountry getTax xs =
    xs
    |> Seq.filter (fun row -> getId row <> "---")
    |> Seq.filter (fun row -> getCountry row <> "South America")
    |> Seq.filter (fun row -> getTax row <> 0.0)
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> getCountry row)
    |> Seq.map (fun (country, rows) -> country, (rows |> Seq.averageBy (fun row -> getTax row))))
    |> List.ofSeq
```

This lets you simplify the syntax somewhat:

```
let snippet2 getId getCountry getTax xs =
    xs
    |> Seq.filter (getId >> (<>) "---")
    |> Seq.filter (getCountry >> (<>) "South America")
    |> Seq.filter (getTax >> (<>) 0.0)
    |> Seq.groupBy getCountry
    |> Seq.map (fun (country, rows) -> country, (rows |> Seq.averageBy getTax))
    |> List.ofSeq
```

You can declare type-specific instances of the function with partial application:

```
let snippetForCsvFile1 (xs : CsvFile1 seq) = xs |> snippet2 (fun r -> r.Id) (fun r -> r.Country) (fun r -> r.Tax)
```

Then your switch could look like this:

```
let rawdata csvfile =
    match csvfile with
    | 1 -> snippetForCsvFile1 CsvFile1
    | 2 -> snippetForCsvFile2 CsvFile2
    | 3 -> snippetForCsvFile3 CsvFile3
    | 4 -> snippetForCsvFile4 CsvFile4
    | _ -> failwith "Not a File"
```

This then ought to work with your last expression:

```
let raw =
    [ 1 .. 4]
    |> List.collect rawdata
```

The switch in your question has a problem that you didn't mention in your question:

```
let rawdata csvfile =
    let data = 
        match csvfile with
        | 1 -> CsvFile1
        | 2 -> CsvFile2
        | 3 -> CsvFile3
        | 4 -> CsvFile4
        | _ -> failwith "Not a File"
```

The problem here is that the binding of `data` doesn't have a single type.  You could achieve that with an object-oriented approach using an interface (or a base class), but that would not be particularly idiomatic for F#.  A more idiomatic approach would be to declare a discriminated union, but given the example you've posted it doesn't seem necessary.